# fix Junit h2 datasource configuration

Tags: java, spring, oracle, junit, h2

I have Spring project with Oracle DB with following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "oracleTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {
                "com.dsi.system.baseinfo.repositories",
                "com.dsi.system.repositorieslib.*"
        }
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OracleDataSourceConfiguration {

    private final JpaProperties jpaProperties;


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.sample")
    public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.sample.configuration")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return primaryDataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .password("123")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oracleEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = jpaProperties.getJPAProperties("sample");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.dsi.system.core.entities",
                "com.dsi.system.core.sign.entity",
                "com.dsi.system.baseinfo.entities"
        );
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("sample");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "oracleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager oracleTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("chequeEntityManagerFactory")
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean chequeEntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(chequeEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

and I want create my Junit with H2 DB and this is my H2DataSourceConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "h2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "h2TransactionManager",
        basePackages = {
                "com.dsi.system.baseinfo.repositories",
                "com.dsi.system.repositorieslib.*"
        }
)
public class H2DataSourceConfiguration {
    private final JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.h2.datasource.cheque")
    public DataSourceProperties h2PrimaryDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }


    @Bean(name = "h2PrimaryDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Mode.getInstance("ORACLE").numericWithBooleanComparison = true;
        return h2PrimaryDataSourceProperties()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "h2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = jpaProperties.getJPAProperties("sample");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.dsi.system.core.entities",
                "com.dsi.system.core.sign.entity",
                "com.dsi.system.baseinfo.entities"
        );
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("sample");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager h2TransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("h2EntityManagerFactory")
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean h2EntityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(h2EntityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

after run my test I get following **BeanDefinitionOverrideException**:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'batchRevokeRepository' defined in com.dsi.system.repositorieslib.revoke.BatchRevokeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ChequeDataSourceConfiguration: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null; defined in com.dsi.system.repositorieslib.revoke.BatchRevokeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ChequeDataSourceConfiguration] for bean 'batchRevokeRepository' since there is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null; defined in com.dsi.system.repositorieslib.revoke.BatchRevokeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on H2ChequeDataSourceConfiguration] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:372)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:427)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
    ... 72 more
```

if I disable **OracleDataSourceConfiguration** from my code, run test successfully.
maybe I should disable that when my test run but I can't do it and I don't confident this way is correct.
can any one help me to fix it?

thanks :)

Comment: Do you really have multiple datasources in your project? If not use the Sprng Boot test support to simply reconfigure your database automatically.

Comment: yes. I have multiple datasources in project.@M.Deinum

Comment: Just override the datasource I don't see why you reconfigure everything.

Comment: Can you explain more? @M.Deinum

Comment: I don't see why you are reconfiguring everything. You should only need to reconfigure the datasource, everything else should stay the same (or maybe even better, don't use H2 but testcontainers with an actual Oracle database).